# Unable to load 45k root url in the laravel web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, amazon-lightsail

My client have 7896 pages on previous website
URL of older website like: [www.domain.com/{url}](http://www.domain.com/%7Burl%7D)

Now client want to make new website but he need same url structure as older one ([www.domain.com/{url}](http://www.domain.com/%7Burl%7D))

Client have approx 45k blog post in different category & this need to be manage from laravel admin panel.

If i need to do that than i have 45k url in the root domain like ([www.domain.com/{url}](http://www.domain.com/%7Burl%7D)),  here issue comes in that there are new development in the website also with route like

([www.domain.com/category/{cat_url}](http://www.domain.com/category/%7Bcat_url%7D))
([www.domain.com/tags/{cat_url}](http://www.domain.com/tags/%7Bcat_url%7D))

I have 45k blog url in the web.php file

[www.domain.com/{url}](http://www.domain.com/%7Burl%7D)

Issue list

- memory limit issue
- slow performance issue (4.5 sec to load page, on each request load 45k url in the route)

now in the aws server i m facing issue related to memory timeout as i have large amount of URL in the root that is loaded into memory.

Error Message:

```
local.ERROR: Out of memory (allocated 38469632) (tried to allocate 3170560 bytes) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Out of memory (allocated 38469632) (tried to allocate 3170560 bytes) at /domain.com/routes/dynamic_blog_routes.php:33026)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

- I can not change URL structure as seo is already very well

Is there any way that we can solve this? Insted of 45k url in web.php to only 1 function or menthod we can use that?

Please share your solution or guide me on this.

My web.php file like.

```
<?php
Route::get('test-blog', 'Front\BlogController@blog_details');
Route::get('hello-world', 'Front\BlogController@blog_details');
--- 45k routes like this ---
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your overall setup, so people can reproduce it. Include that in your Q, along with the output it produces. In general, don't paraphrase what you did and what happened, provide verifiable facts instead. Also, search for the error message online, maybe someone encountered the same and solved it already.

Comment: Why you even created new route for each blog? Please read [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing) before getting started to create project. 45k routes is not acceptable for any situation and any project

Comment: Why not use a database for this?

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli issue is client have limiterd pages and created long time ago now he want to create new site but url remains same as all url's are already indexed in the google. also he want all url in the root after domain name

Comment: "client have limiterd pages" - what does that mean? Why do you need all these routes in the `web.php` for these "limited pages"?

Comment: @BhargavPatel You can keep same urls for requests but you will need to add or change some logic in project. Just define single route like: `Route::get('{blog_name}' ...` and use `$blog_name` variable in controller to filter blogs and return requested one

Comment: @NicoHaase client have older website with limited pages now client want new website but he need older url with new website so this issue comes as all the urls are in root

Comment: I still don't get what "limited pages" needs. Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase updated question so you can clearly understand that.

Comment: What does `dynamic_blog_routes.php` do? How is it related to `web.php`?

Comment: dynamic_blog_routes.php have multiple routes of the blog 

`<?php
Route::get('test-blog', 'Front\BlogController@blog_details');
Route::get('hello-world', 'Front\BlogController@blog_details');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vüsal Hüseynli

Based on your comment i have solved this issue.

My web.php file

```
<?php
Route::get('category/{any}', 'Front\BlogController@cat_details');
Route::get('tags/{any}', 'Front\BlogController@tag_details');
Route::get('{any}', 'Front\BlogController@blog_details');
?>
```

My BlogController.php file

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function blog_details(Request $request)
    {
      $urlSegment = $request->segment(1);
      if(empty($urlSegment)){
          abort(404);
      }
      $blog = Blog::where("slug", "=", $urlSegment)->first();
      dd($blog);
    }
}
```

I can access all my blog routes as well as other urls that is not part of the blog.